# MPI application freezes in cluster configuration using a big set of libraries

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing, mpj-express

I have developed a MPI application using Java and MPJ Expresss. It works perfectly in the multi-core configuration.

Recently, it was given to my access to the distributed memory environment in order to test my application. First, I did the MPJ HelloWorld application to check that the cluster configuration was working well. After that, I proceeded to run my application, but it freezes after showing:

MPJ Express (0.38) is started in the cluster configuration

To make things worse, I killed the process with Ctrl+C and I couldn't run the HelloWorld application. I had to kill the MPJ daemon in all machines and start them again.

I even replace the content of my main class with the same content of the HelloWorld class to see if it printed something. It didn't. Also, I created a HelloWorld application with a similar package structure to my application and the HelloWorld worked great.

One of the big differences I can notice between the HelloWorld and my application is that I have a set of libraries which size is around 29.8 MB, so I tried not adding the libraries to the execution class path. It worked, but of course, my application is useless because it can't find its required libraries at run time.

I would appreciate any comments and advices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visit **mpj-express.org/readme.html**  and select a file based on your platform:

- Linux / UNIX / Mac - http://mpj-express.org/docs/readme/README
- Windows - http://mpj-express.org/docs/readme/README-win.txt

The (Windows) service "MPJ Daemon" should be installed **once**.

Nevertheless, threads are to be started before and halted after **every** MPJ application,
if you are using Eclipse IDE.

Note: On command line, you can start threads, run as many programs as you wish and finally terminate them.

> ---
>
> - Write 'machine' file
> - **Start** daemons: mpjboot machines
> - Compile: javac -cp .:$MPJ_HOME/lib/mpj.jar HelloWorld.java
> - Execute: mpjrun.sh -np 4 -dev niodev HelloWorld
> - **Stop** daemons: mpjhalt machines
>
> ---